# Java programmming- help initialize(carpet)

Tags: java

I have started how to learn Java programming and I a got a problem while doing an asignment:
ps this is a c programming assignment, using it to do a java programming:

> Consider a (potentially large commercial) room that has floor dimensions length len and width wid. The area of the floor is given by multiplying len by wid.
>
> Carpet tiles are provided as individual squares (2 feet by 2 feet). Write, compile and run a C program, carpet.c, that
>
> -calculates the minimum number of carpet tiles that are needed to cover a room whose dimensions (len and wid) are input from the terminal (measurements are in inches). NB: floor tiles can be cut to fit at the edges of the room - try to minimise waste.
>
> -calculates how many carpet-tile packs are needed. The supplier only provides carpet tiles in packs of ten (i.e. individual tiles cannot be purchased separately).
>
> -calculates how many spare tiles are left over once the minimum number of packs have been purchased.
>
> -prints out all these results in a neat table along with the total cost of the order. (A pack of tiles costs $50 for each of the first four packs, and the price reduces to $45 for each subsequent pack.)
>
> Think carefully about how are you going to test your program? The calculations are non-trivial and easy to get wrong. If your program doesn't work then you will waste the company a lot of money and you will probably lose the contract to supply the software.
>
> You should write out a number of test cases (by hand) that cover all the different possibilities that could happen. Don't forget to consider various boundary cases too - these are often where errors are detected.

So far I have done:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class carpet {
    public static void main (String args[]){
    Scanner scanf = new Scanner (System.in);

        float len, wid;
        float area;

        int roundTiles;
        int roundPacks;

        float tarea;
        float tpack;
        float NoOfTiles;
        float NoOfPacks;
        float tspares1;
        float tspares2;
        int packCost;
        int cost;

        tarea= 12* 12;
        tpack= 10;

        System.out.format("Enter the length of the room, Inches: ");
        len = scanf.nextFloat();

        System.out.format("Enter the width of the room, Inches: ");
        wid = scanf.nextFloat();

        area = len * wid;

        NoOfTiles = area/ tarea;
        NoOfPacks = NoOfTiles/tpack;


        roundTiles = (int) Math.ceil(NoOfTiles);
        roundPacks = (int) Math.ceil(NoOfPacks);



        tspares1 = roundPacks * 10;
        tspares2 = tspares1 - roundTiles;

        if (roundPacks <= 4)
            packCost =50;
        else if(roundPacks > 4)
        {
            packCost = 45;
            packCost = packCost + 20;   *<<-----******LINE 50-----*********

        }


        cost =roundPacks * packCost; *<<*******---ERROR-------------*********

        System.out.println(cost);

        }

}
```

**The error says:** *"The local variable packCost may not have been initialized"*

**AND the compiler says:** *"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The local variable packCost may not have been initialized
    at carpet.main(carpet.java:50)
"*

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise `packetCost`:

```
int packCost = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the variable **packCost**  by doing replacing the current line:

```
int packCost;
```

by

```
int packCost=0;
```

You are initializing your packCost variable in a conditional statement and the compiler is not smart enough to detect it.

Answer (score 1):

Using else instead of else-if makes it clear to the compiler that one of the conditions will be executed, so packCost is always set:

```
if (roundPacks <= 4)
    packCost = 50;
else
{
    packCost = 45;
    packCost = packCost + 20;
}
```

Comment: +1 good catch that the if/else-if really should have been an if/else

Answer (score 0):

In Java, local variables need to be initialized.  If this was a field variable, it would have an implicit default value of 0 (zero).

Here is a link that explains this: http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/lang/defaults.html (disclaimer: not my page)

From this page:

- Field variables (class members) are automatically initialized to default values
- Local variables (method or constructor variables) are not automatically initialized